# How should the name "Kimia" be spelled?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, spelling, names, american-accent

My name is Kimia, but I have no idea which of the following spellings is right; **Kimia** or **Kimya**. I gotta say the last syllable of my name is pronounced like **Mia**. Would you tell me which one is correct?

Comment: https://www.behindthename.com/ is a good resource to see how names are commonly spelled.

Answer (score 4):

There are three possibilities.

If your native language uses the Latin ABC, then use exactly the same spelling as in your native language.  So a person in France would use the same letters for their name in English. (It might be necessary for the computer to drop accents, but such old software is becoming rarer)

If your native language has a standard system for conversion to the Latin ABC, then use that standard system.  For example, in (modern) greek, alpha-> A, beta (veta) -> v.  In Greek, iota become "i" and upsilon becomes "y". In Mandarin, use the pinyin system.  Japanese has two systems: Hepburn and kunrei, you can choose either (most choose Hepburn).

There is Persian name (کیمیا), which is normally written "Kimia".  There is also a Japanese name that would be written "Kimiya"

Finally, if you language is rare enough that there is no standard nor commonly used system for converting to ABC, you can choose. If there is no standard, there is no right nor wrong way to convert a name to the Latin script

Answer (score 3):

Names do not normally change spelling in different language, much less different regional versions of a language, unless a different alphabet or writing system is also involved. Your name is your name. There is no "**correct**" spelling of a name, except the original spelling, or the one the person whose name it is prefers.

As it is your name, you may choose how you want it spelled, and how you want it pronounced. But if official documents (such as IDs) have a particular spelling, it is usually easier and simpler to stick with that spelling.

Legally, a person may choose any name, and any spelling of that name, and as long as this is not done to defraud anyone or to conceal crime, it is legal and effective, even without court action.